# Firebase Util NormalizedCollection error with AngularFire

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, firebase-util

This is the error message I get : **Cannot read property 'NormalizedCollection' of undefined**
I downloaded it with `bower install firebase-util` and inserted it in my Ionic project (in the index page).

```
angular.module('starter')
.controller('ProjetsEncoursCtrl', function($scope,$firebaseArray, $ionicListDelegate, $ionicHistory,$ionicPopup,  $localStorage, $timeout, liste_demandes, infos_demandes) {

              var ref = firebase.database().ref();
              var nc = new firebase.util.NormalizedCollection(
              ref.child('accounts/'+$localStorage.accountId),
              ref.child('demandes')
            ).select('demandes.ajout_le', 'demandes.localisation')
            .ref();

            $scope.items = $firebaseArray(nc);
```

**Can you please help me with this ?**

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i removed firebase-util then re-install the new beta version for Firebase v3 and it worked.

```
bower uninstall firebase-util
```

then

```
bower install https://github.com/GartorwareCorp/firebase-util.git#v0.3.0gt
```